# UTM-alternative for adding parameters with exiting Analytics campaign terms

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, cookie, url-parameters

I'm using the excellent UTM-alernative by dm-guy [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68795/is-it-possible-to-track-url-parameter-and-then-value-of-cookie/68797#68797) to create a cookie and inject the campaign source into a form. However, although that works extremely well for the form, the UTM replacement `/?src=mybannercampaignsource` doesn't show up in Analytics in the *Aquisition -> Source/Medium* section as it did with the traditional `?utm_source=etc.etc`.

My question is whether there is any way to add to the `/?src=` to include parameters that Google Analytics recognizes, or whether there is some other way of handling this in Google Analytics

Comment: Hi Chris, if I may ask, why don't you use the good-old utm parameters of google analytics (utm_source, utm_campaign.. and etc.) together with the new "src" query string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add JavaScript code before the Google Analytics tracking code to decode the parameters of the URL:

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? null : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var source = getParameterByName('src');
</script>
```

and modify GA tracking code to match the parameters with GA standard variables:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-YY', 'auto');
ga('set', {
'campaignSource': source,
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly :) Thankyou very much